# Do military ranks transfer between regiments?

Tags: en-garde

If a character has [joined a regimen](http://patriot.net/~aquazoo/eg/eg_rules/eg_RlzFrm.html)t and they decide to join another instead do they retain the same rank they achieved in their previous regiment or do they have to buy their rank again?

E.g. If you're a Captain of the 4th Arquebusiers and decide to join the Royal Marines, are you still a Captain? Can you just change regiments like that?

Comment: It would depends if you can afford the [cost of the commission](http://www.colonialwargaming.co.uk/Miscellany/Army/Commissions.htm)...

Comment: In addition to this; can you buy promotions once you've joined? Or is it "change regiment" to do that?

Comment: Historically, you could sell your commission, so in theory you could sell your commission in one regiment and buy it (for about the same price, depending on "market conditions"/politics/etc.) in a different regiment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have to rebuy your commission in any new regiment you join.

That means paying up for the your desired rank and any rank lower than the one you are buying.

The exception would be serving at the frontier or in the RNHR where you keep your commission (as you maintain your place in your existing regiment).

Comment: Dangnabbit! I ~hope~ you at least retain your rank in your former regiment if you for some reason rejoin!

Answer (score 2):

To supplement wax eagles' answer:

Ranks above Major are not transferrable without:

1. Resigning.
2. Buying a commission in the new regiment to Major.
3. Using "influence" to gain instantaneous promotion to Lieutenant Colonel or higher.

Which is exactly the same process and buying yourself a Colonelcy.

Comment: Influence by itself will never get you promotion, though it can be used to persuade NPCs to resign and allow you to buy your way up. The whole point of this process is that it is *not* instantaneous.